# fwrite function behaves unexpected

Tags: fwrite

I am using `fwrite` function. I have a file that has 4K. I want to change a field in the place 3500.
I do fseek to the place (3500) I also get it in `ftell` that tells me that I'm at 3500.
I do:

```
char[8] a;   
File* f; //is opened with a+ mode    
int n = fwrite(a, 1, 8, f);
```

Then when I open the file the data from buffer a is set to the end of the file. 
Why? How to change it?

Answer (score 1):

Because you opened the file with "a+", anything you write to the file will always go at the end of the file regardless of seeking to anywhere else. The "a" means you open the file in appending mode. Use "r+" for the mode instead.

Comment: Ok thanks, I used a+ for assuring that the file if not exists will be. Can I use something else ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You would have to open the file with "r+", and if that fails try open it with "w+".